# Pandas read_json - Stop convert index to datetime

Tags: json, pandas

I have the below data in a a.json file.

```
{
  "1000000000": {
    "TEST": 2
  }
}
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r"a.json", dtype= str, orient='index', convert_dates=False)
print(df)
```

Getting output as :

```
                TEST
2001-09-09 01:46:40    2
```

Expected :

```
                TEST
1000000000         2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need parameter `convert_axes=False` in [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html):

You can use it like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("a.json", dtype= str, orient='index',convert_axes=False ,convert_dates=False)
print(df)
```